# Is it worth using the most expensive salvage kits on low level items?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Is it worth using master's salvage kits on loot from low level areas? Will I get rare materials from them, or would it rather be more efficient (profit wise) to use low level kits on low level items?

Comment: As far as I know, the basic point of master salvage kits is for guaranteed chances of extract things like runes and sigils? Low level equipment and salvage junk will only ever give you the equivalent materials no matter what level kit you use.

Comment: Rewrite this as an answer Gwen, I believe you're correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On any item the high level kits increase the chances of getting rare materials. Having said that if you wanted basic mats you could use a basic salvage kit.

Comment: Item quality does not matter in terms of salvaging?

Comment: It may be more worth it to buy the low level rare mats off the trading post (when it starts working) instead of using expensive high-level salvage kits to get them off low level items.

Answer (score 0):

I use basic kits for most stuff, and keep a single high level kit that I use only when I want the rune/ sigil. ATM I don't think the resale value justifies salvage for sale, but maybe I'm not in the high enough areas yet to tell.

Remember if manufacturing stuff to get your craft level up you can salvage stuff you've made and recycle the mats; advance salvage to get jewels/sigils back, then reuse to invent a different item for yet more xp. Can be a cost effective way to make xp.

Comment: Welcome to the site Gothmog2. Do note that this is a question and answer site. So keep the subjective, this is what I do to a minimum and the objective, here are some results/calculations/references to a maximum. Easier cost effective is always good of course ;).